# Socket threads hang in timeout block

Tags: python, sockets, gevent

I'm trying to calculate the time it takes to receive all data from a given socket, so I'm using 'with Timeout(5, False)' to wait 5 seconds for data and then save the time of last recv.  However, the current code just sits and hangs when I supply more than one thread.  I'd like help figuring out why it just hangs when it should timeout.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time
from gevent import socket, Timeout
from gevent.pool import Pool

def calc_wait(website):
    data = ''
    start = stop = time.time()
    sock_buffer = ''

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((website,80))
    s.send('HEAD / HTTP/1.1\n\n')

    with Timeout(5, False):
        while True:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if data:
                sock_buffer += data
                stop = time.time()

    print ('Recieved {0} bytes in {1} seconds from {2}'
           .format(len(sock_buffer), stop-start, s.getpeername()))

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":

    targs = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'bing.com',\
             'tide.com', 'monkey.com', 'python.com',\
             'a.com', 'b.com', 'c.com', 'd.com']

    pool = Pool(10)
    for t in targs:
        pool.spawn(calc_wait, t)
    pool.join()
```

Comment: /me trollface 
Is there a reason you can't use twisted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that the socket hangs but that you never break when the socket ends, creating an infinite loop. Here's the code needed to fix it:

```
with Timeout(5, False):
    while 1:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break

        sock_buffer += data
        stop = time.time()
```

EDIT:
Once the socket completes its connection, it won't yield the greenlet thread even though you're calling `#recv`. So if you want the timeout to be able to fire you need to manually yield with `gevent.sleep()`:

```
with Timeout(5, False):
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if data:
            sock_buffer += data
            stop = time.time()

        gevent.sleep()
```

From the gevent docs: "Calling sleep with seconds of 0 is the canonical way of expressing a cooperative yield."

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that would defeat the purpose of the Timeout block.  Once data is received I want it to wait and see if more data comes in, and do this for 5 seconds.  If i break after the first receive then I can't accomplish this. I'm implementing this general idea in environments where connections can be slow and data isn't received all at once.  Ultimately, I'm trying to figure out the wait time per socket to wait for data.  This is my approach to calculating that wait time. Thoughts?

Comment: Also, keep in mind my approach will work with a single thread, but hangs on multiple threads.

Comment: Ahh, I see what your asking. I updated my post with the answer.

Comment: That got me a lot further - thank you! It no longer hangs, however, now a few threads have empty buffers and finish without ever receiving any data.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure that a.com, b.com and c.com resolve to anything. Could these be causing your problem?

Comment: They do resolve fine. And if I only specify one thread with Pool(1), every host receives data.  However, once I get them all in a pool with Pool(10), some consistently never receive any data.

Comment: Hmm, when I run it, all of mine receive at least 148 bytes of data.

Comment: Maybe its a non-standard tcp port related issue - no clue.. i was testing this solution in my script (http://daggumit.com/code/smartbruter.py) on port 9002 when i experienced that problem.  The code in this post does work as u described.  If u can identify the issue in my linked script let me know. If not, thank you very much for your assistance and getting me further.