# Socket recv hangs despite settimeout

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using the built-in socket module to create a client socket.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
sock.settimeout(30.0)
sock.connect((host, port))
...

def recvall(sock, count):
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    while count:
        newbuf = sock.recv(count)
        buf.write(newbuf)
        count -= len(newbuf)
    return buf.getvalue()

msg = recvall(sock, 1024)
```

Sometimes, despite the timeout setting, the `recv` call will block forever when the server process crashes. Unfortunately I can't create a minimal example; my example with a minimal server has the correct behavior.

Comment: Then your example is *not* minimal. If the problem is with a crashing server, a minimal example should emulate a crashing server.

Comment: Is the `sock.recv` inside a loop by any chance, from which the code fails to break if there is a timeout? Like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998715/socket-threads-hang-in-timeout-block

Comment: mkrieger: I've tried minimal examples with a crashing server. I suspect that my example isn't crashing in the right way. Indeed recv is in the loop. D'oh, that may be the answer -- great suggestion! Checking now.

Comment: That's exactly the same problem - if `len(newbuf)` is 0, there is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by mkrieger1's comment. The `recv` call was returning the empty string, causing an infinite loop.

```
if not newbuf:
    raise socket.error("no data")
```

Comment: Well then poor reporting on your part, maybe poor observation. An infinite loop isn't the same thing as blocking forever.